# Jquery upload image via base64 alternative

Tags: ratchet, todataurl, base64url

On my site is use ratchet websocket. When i try to send an image to the webserver i previously used base64 encoding. Encode the image to base64 and send via ratchet websocket.
But for this project PHP is running on 32 bit machine; therefor Ratchet craches because it cant process the base64 incomming data as it doent support 64 bit.

`var DataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');`
creates a to large value for Ratchet to receive on server.

*64-bit format codes are not available for 32-bit versions of PHP in /var/www/projectname/websocket/vendor/ratchet/rfc6455/src/Messaging/MessageBuffer.php:163
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/projectname/websocket/vendor/ratchet/rfc6455/src/Messaging/MessageBuffer.php(163): unpack()*

[[source from someone else who has this problem](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/792)]

Installing 64 version of PHP isnt an option because server is 32 bit.

Alternative i created is a separate upload script via AJAX and only send the image-name (created on client) via ratchet. Not the whole image. The benefit of using base64 is that i can use same dataurl as css-background-url.

This alternative is very impractical. E.g.cant use some data on the server to include in the image-name (or i have to retrieve it beforehand). And i have to link to the image instead of using the already existing dataurl.

**My question:** can i send the image via ratchet by encoding it via a different way that supports 32 bit machines? I read about blob and some other things.

Search google for a couple hours but couldnt find a decent answer.